# Graceful container shutdown timeout in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Kafka service with ~100 partitions deployed on a Docker Swarm cluster.
When the service is shutting down (due to update or machine reboot), Kafka has not enough time to write snapshots of all partitions to disk, logs show that it finishes only about 70% of partitions and then gets killed by Docker after 10s timeout, and then it takes about 10 minutes to recover after abnormal shutdown.

I tried to find a way to increase this timeout globally or per container, but I found just a `--stop-timeout` parameter for the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command.

Am I missing something here, or Docker Swarm in fact doesn't have a proper way to delay killing a container? Maybe there is at least a workaround for cases like mine?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the stop_grace_period (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#stop_grace_period) ?

Comment: The `stop_grace_period` works fine for `docker-compose up`, but seems to be ignored when I use `docker stack deploy`.